# RTrim is not working when sentence is Arabic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

`RTrim` is not working when sentence is Arabic.

Below is the example

```
declare @name nvarchar(50);
set @name = N' لللييب بي  ';
select rtrim(ltrim(@name));
```

English one is working

```
declare @name nvarchar(50);
set @name = ' This is test message ';
select rtrim(ltrim(@name));
```

Comment: Have you tried using a specific `COLLATE` value?

Comment: What is the compatibility-level of the database you're using? (And why are you still running SQL Server 2008 R2?)

Comment: FWIW, this works for me in SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL: `SELECT TRIM( N' لللييب بي  ' ) AS t;`

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following.

Casting as `VARBINARY` data type allows to see what exact characters represent white spaces in the string. It could be SPACE character (0x2000), but could be something else. If it is something else, the `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` functions won't work.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(50) ;
SET @name = N' لللييب بي  ' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS;

SELECT @name AS [Before], DATALENGTH(@name) AS [Before_Len]
    , TRY_CAST(@name AS VARBINARY(30)) AS [Before_Binary]
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(@name)) AS [After], DATALENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(@name))) AS [After_Len];

-- check available Arabic collations
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE name LIKE 'Arabic%';
```

| Before | Before_Len | Before_Binary | After | After_Len |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| لللييب بي | 24 | 0x20004406440644064A064A062806200028064A0620002000 | لللييب بي | 18 |

Comment: Many thanks for code, but other arabic text not working like SET @name = N'السلام عليكم  ' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS;

Comment: You can try some other Arabic collations

Comment: Some arabic works and some not

Comment: I updated the answer. Check it out.